# online estimation of autoregressive process

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

I am interested about online estimation of autoregressive models. Is there anything I can find in the literature about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in reading the paper [Efficient Online Estimation of Autoregressive Parameters](http://personal.rhul.ac.uk/ukah/113/AR.pdf) by T. Sharia.

It is instructive to work out the details of the AR(1) case beforehand. In this case you have the model

$$x_{t+1} = \beta_t x_t + \varepsilon_t$$

with

$$\beta_t = \frac{\sum_{s=1}^tx_sx_{s-1}}{\sum_{s=1}^tx_{s-1}^2}$$

By considering $\beta_{t+1} - \beta_t$ and rearranging, you can derive

$$\beta_{t+1} = \beta_t + ( x_{t+1} - \beta_tx_t) \frac{x_t}{I_{t+1}}$$

$$I_{t+1} = I_t + x_t^2$$

where $I_t$ is the quantity $\sum_{s=1}^tx_{t-1}^2$.

This has an intuitive appeal - the autoregressive estimator at the next time step is the current autoregressive parameter, plus a correction proportional to the prediction error at the current step.